# Как удалить пользователя full_name?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как удалить пользователя, по full_name по нескольким ключевым словам, а не по одному, а так же, как удалить сообщение, так как, только пользователя удаляет, но сообщение, остается в группе.

Сделал так, все идеально работает

```py
if message.from_user.full_name == 'Менеджер':
    await bot.kick_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
    await message.delete()
    return
```

Но как сделать, если например, у меня будет 10, каждый что ли по отдельности, хотелось бы, чтобы из этой строки брал, пока только 2 записал, как это, всё прописать?

```
bmenbers = ['Менеджер', 'Manager']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть так:

```
if message.from_user.full_name in bmenbers:
    await bot.kick_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
    await message.delete()
    return
```